# InvoiceId (or equivalent) missing from EA usage billing

Tags: azure-billing-api

Hoping someone can help with this.

I'm pulling usage information from the Azure API:

> https://consumption.azure.com/v3/enrollments/{enrollment}/usagedetails/submit?startTime=2019-08-01&endTime=2019-08-31

Which will return a url (when status is 3) to a csv blob similar to this:

> https://ccmreportstoragewestus.blob.core.windows.net/publicapireports/...

What I don't see in the API result is anything pertaining to an invoice reference.  When I've done this with AWS, most of the time you have an invoiceid/reference, in cases where you may have had more than one paper bill for that billing period.

Am I missing something with the EA billing API?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, EA customers get invoices on a quarterly basis. If you've a hard/soft copy of invoice, you can pull this data using Azure Consumption APIs by providing correct offer name and the billing period parameters.

Answered this previously on the [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8adaea4b-3f2c-4e0c-ac74-a9e912d72793/ea-usage-api-with-invoiceid?forum=windowsazurepurchasing).